# A weird property of odd positive integers $n$ with $\sigma(n)\sim2n $

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-number-theory

When one looks at positive odd integers $n$ for which $|\sigma(n)-2n|\le\log n$, (sequence A088012) it appears that for all seven known numbers of this type the abundance, $\sigma(n)-2n$ is $\equiv 6\bmod 12$. Is there a relatively simple reason for that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's two parts of this: $\sigma(n) - 2n$ being congruent to $2$ mod $4$ and being divisible by $3$. Since $n$ is odd, $2n$ is congruent to $2$ mod $4$, so the first part is explained by $\sigma(n)$ being divisible by $4$, which is easy: Every number with at least two odd prime factors with odd multiplicity has divisor sum divisible by $4$, which is the vast majority of numbers that might potentially appear on this list.

All these numbers are divisible by $3$, so $\sigma(n)-2n$ is divisible by $3$ if and only if $\sigma(n)$ is divisible by $3$, which happens if $n$ has a prime factor congruent to $2$ mod $3$ with odd multiplicity (or congruent to $1$ mod $3$ with multiplicity divisible by three). These numbers are abundant, which requires having a lot of small prime factors, so it's unsurprising that they are divisible by the smallest odd prime, $3$, as well as some of the next $3$ primes, at least one of them with multiplicity one. (In fact, all but one of these numbers is divisible by $5$ with multiplicity one.)